# who calls Activity.dispatchTouchEvent( event )?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-touch-event

I am trying to add touch events from a file to the current application (build a new touch event according to the data found in the file ), and I am trying to understand the chain of calls when a "real" touch event is triggered.

From all the searches I conducted, I found that `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)` is the first method called when we have a touch event, then its forwarded to `ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent` and then to `View.dispatchTouchEvent`.

I want to find what is being called before `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)` and how the events is transferred from the HW to this method.

Comment: Why do you have to simulate the actual touch event?  Can you just call the code that would be called by the touch event instead?

Comment: I want to control one device by another device,I build a connection which transfers the events from the controlling device via WIFI-p2p to the controlled device, saves them in a file in a specific format, and then on the controlled device I need to read the events from the file, build event objects and inject them somehow to the currently running application without changing the application and without assuming I know the code of this app.
So that is why I cant call the code of the app, I want to catch the method which calls to Activity.dispatchTouchEvent and try to mess with the code there

Comment: use Thread.dumpStackTrace()

Comment: @Foad - Were you ever able to figure it out?

Comment: @myCodeHurts no I didn't

Answer (score 3):

Maybe what you want is how android input framework works. The following blog about android input framework architecture may helps you.

[Android Input Framework Architecture[Part 1] : Introduction to InputReader & InputDispatcher](http://strayinsights.blogspot.com/2018/08/android-input-framework.html)

The input process can simply be put as:

input hardware  ------>   kernel/driver(input protocol)  -----> EventHub(framework/base/libs/ui)  getevent------> InputReader ----> inputDispatcher ---->  Window manager.

1. First, InputReader convert the meta input event to android event (etc. MotionEvent/KeyEvent).
2. Then, InputDispatcher dispatcher the event to WindowManager
3. WindowManager calls Window.Callback.dispatchTouchEvent(***).

Answer (score 2):

In Activty the method dispatchTouchEvent is :

```
 public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        onUserInteraction();
    }
    if (getWindow().superDispatchTouchEvent(ev)) {
        return true;
    }
    return onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

you must call `super.dispatchTouchEvent()` method in ur own activity.

so that u can reach this line `:getWindow().superDispatchTouchEvent(ev)`

`getWindwow()` return the instance of **PhoneWindow**.

`PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent()` will call the DecorView's method 
,and in that method ,`DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent` will be called.

So the event has been passed to the views.

```
    //in Class PhoneWindow
 public boolean superDispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      return mDecor.superDispatchTouchEvent(event);
 }
```

and

```
//in class DecorView
public boolean superDispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```